# Edge Issues Tool - Ignore Specific Source File

Tags: microsoft-edge, devtools

I'd like to use the microsoft edge issues tool, to analyze my application for possible improvements.
Unfortunately libraries like bootstrap or materializecss contain warnings, which appear in the issues tool. And I'd like to ignore those files.

I already read through the [microsoft documentation of that tool](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/microsoft-edge/devtools-guide-chromium/issues/) and it didn't really mention an option to ignore those files...

It does have that checkbox "Include Third Party Issues", but that would just exclude files form external services. And I dont want to load anything from any external provider for security reasons. External resources are blocked through CSP, so that checkbox is not really in option here...

Does anyone know how to ignore specific files in the issues tool and the issues tool only?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Unfortunately, currently you can only filter issues by severity instead of by their sources. You can request this feature in Microsoft Edge by sending feedback to the Dev Team (press **Alt+Shift+I**).

Comment: Thanks. In that case i can stop searching for that feature...

Comment: And just for the record. I submitted that as feedack through Alt+Shift+I. Thanks for the hint. :)

Comment: @Canabale, You're welcome. Hope we'll have this feature in the future.